# PSEXEC - Not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: batch-file, psexec

Attempting to copy files onto target computer within the same network but having issues specifically with the psexec portion. The files copy over into the target computers correct location, but then I get the error 'psexec' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Start.bat

```
echo off
FOR /f %%i in (c:\Temp\software\computerlist.txt) Do (md \\%%i\c$\temp\software
    Echo %%i
    if exist \\%%i\c$\temp\software (
        copy "c:\Temp\software\InstallSetup.exe" \\%%i\c$\temp\software
        copy "c:\Temp\software\Install.bat" \\%%i\c$\temp\software
        psexec \\%%i \\%%i\c$\temp\software\Install.bat
    )
)
pause
```

Install.bat

```
msiexec.exe /I "c:\temp\software\InstallSetup.exe" BIMODE=1 /l*v c:\temp\software\install.log /qn /norestart
```

From my understanding, because the psexec is not located within c:\Windows\System32 directory, it's failing because of this reason. If possible, I don't want to have to download psexec and push it out to other computers to make this work. Thoughts on how I can correct this?

Comment: `psexec` doesn't have to be on your target computers, but it _does_ have to be on your source computer. Is it installed? If so, try providing the full path to it instead of just calling `psexec`.

Comment: No, it's not installed on the source computer. I can install that now and see if that fixes it. I thought it needed to be on the destination computers.

Comment: File and Printer Sharing has to be enabled on the target machine, but that's it.

Comment: @SomethingDark once I provided the full path, the script started to work but errored out with Code 1620. Haven't read into it yet.

Comment: @SomethingDark do you think it could be the fact I am trying to call a .exe file within the install.bat? Unfortunately I don't have an option to install through .msi file type.

Comment: Yep, searching Google for "psexec error 1620" suggests that `msiexec` is unhappy that you're passing it an exe file instead of an msi file. Try running `InstallSetup.exe` by itself instead.

Comment: Within my installsetup.bat file, the only code I have is @echo off and start c:\temp\software\installsetup.exe and it gives me error code 0 which indicated success, but nothing happens. Nothing starts to actually run which is the issue.